# How to convert Php source code to Asp.net code

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an application on mybloglog. I got the source code in php.I dont have any idea about php. Thats why I want to  convert Php source code to Asp.net code. Any Help Please

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

[PHP to ASP.NET 1.x Migration Assistant](http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived/migration-assistants/php-to-aspnet/)

> The PHP to ASP.NET Migration Assistant
>   is designed to help you convert PHP
>   pages and applications to ASP.NET. It
>   does not make the conversion process
>   completely automatic, but it will
>   speed up your project by automating
>   some of the steps required for
>   migration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried PHP to ASP.NET 1.x Migration Assistant software but I dont have Php software installed in my system. I need to install Php or without that also i can do? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you'll have to rewrite this code.

PHP is a dynamically-typed, interpreted language. C# (and any other language that runs on the CLR) is statically-typed and compiled.

If you are a web developer I recommend porting the site yourself. You should learn about PHP and how it differs from .NET.

They are two completely different paradigms in web development - knowing both will only make you stronger.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

Hire a ASP.net developer who knows PHP as well