# Convert ASP.net source code to PHP

Tags: php, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert Php source code to Asp.net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291985/how-to-convert-php-source-code-to-asp-net-code)

Can we convert ASP.net source code into PHP .

Any helpful answered much appreciated .

Thanks Regal Singh

Comment: I think you mean automatically, if yes LET ME KNOW!!!

Answer (score 3):

> Can we convert ASP.net source code into PHP .

Yes you can.

Comment: since (s)he is asking the question, apparently the better answer is no, YOU cannot

Comment: @Pleun, no, (s)he can. (S)he should just need to learn PHP and ASP.NET if this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search turned up [this](http://www.design215.com/toolbox/translator/trans_login.php).  It won't do everything, but it should get you started and save you some time.

For something a little more serious, take a look at [ASPA](http://rainbow.cs.unipi.gr/projects/aspa).  I'm not sure how up-to-date it is, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a tool specifically for this, I would doubt it. But yes you can manually port asp.net to php your only hurdle is going to be .net's custom form controls like gridviews and the like. You'd also need to account for the viewstate if that were something you were using heavily in your .net web app.

For an experience php developer it shouldn't be much hassle, for a pure .Net developer it would probably be more troublesome trying to figure out how to do certain things in php that you take for granted in .net.